# statsmodels installation failed with ValueError

Tags: python, linux, pandas, centos, statsmodels

I was trying to install statsmodels, using "pip install statsmodels"
but its failing, with following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
        check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 116, in check_dependency_versions
        from pandas.version import version as pversion
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
        from pandas.io.api import *
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 7, in <module>
        from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 626, in <module>
        .format(openpyxl_compat.start_ver, openpyxl_compat.stop_ver))
    ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Complete error : http://pastebin.com/SVE2yDQS

Answer (score 2):

This is a pandas bug on Python 2.6 only. Soon to be fixed in the next minor release. As a workaround you can install openpyxl.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7284

Comment: I have installed openpyxl-2.0.3 but still getting error in "pip install statsmodels"

Comment: Well, what does the error say now? If it has anything to do with openpyxl it's a pandas issue and probably best to follow up on the github link I provided.

Comment: its the same original error which I have posted here http://pastebin.com/SVE2yDQS

Comment: Ok, well here's what you can do. Since installing openpyxl is reported to work on that github issue, make sure that pip uses the same python that openpyxl was installed to/make sure openpyxl was installed correctly, upgrade from Python 2.6, download and install pandas master instead of using 0.14.0, wait for pandas 0.14.1, or follow up on the github issue linked above to get support for the pandas bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with pandas-0.14.0, Install older version of pandas, then it worked.